# How to type on a new line?

Tags: python

I need to paste all of my data on separate lines so that they arent all smashed together. This is my data:

```
    data = {'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size0+'*** Stock: ***'+stock0+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size1+'*** Stock: ***'+stock1+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size2+'*** Stock: ***'+stock2+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size3+'*** Stock: ***'+stock3+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size4+'*** Stock: ***'+stock4+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size5+'*** Stock: ***'+stock5+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size6+'*** Stock: ***'+stock6+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size7+'*** Stock: ***'+stock7+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size8+'*** Stock: ***'+stock8+'***'
    'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size9+'*** Stock: ***'+stock9+'***'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to format the output you can use `\n` wherever you need the output to go to a newline.

```
data = {'sku: ***'+sku0+'*** Size: ***'+size0+'*** Stock: ***'+stock0+'***\n'
```

if you want to format the code I would suggest using a variables holding each line and then use `+` to add all of them together

Answer (score 0):

If you include '\n' in a string, it will split the line there. For instance:

```
print('This is the first line\nAnd this is the second line')
```

Then the output would be:

```
This is the first line
And this is the second line
```